# Basic matrix manipulation question using transposes

Tags: matrices

If we already know what $X^TX$ and $X\vec{y}$ are, and we append an vector $\vec{x}_*$ to the last row of $X$ and a value $y_*$ to the bottom of $\vec{y}$, how can we show that:
$$X_∗^T X_∗ = X^T X + \vec{x}_∗ \vec{x}_*^T$$
And:
$$X_*\vec{y}_* = X\vec{y} + \vec{x}_*y_*$$
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at block matrix multiplication here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix

Write $X_*=\begin{bmatrix}X\\\dots\\x_*\end{bmatrix}$ and then do the multiplication:
$$X_*^TX_*=[X^T\vdots x_*^T]\begin{bmatrix}X\\\dots\\x_*\end{bmatrix}=X^TX+x_*^Tx_*.$$

Comment: Are you saying the $X$ matrix is made up smaller row block matrices? I think to prove the equalities you'd have to decompose the matrix multiplication itself. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I have added some details to my answer to clarify.